# Cannot set manager attribute using ADSI in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adsi

I update some user information in AD from an HR database.

Text fields or the photo works fine:

```
$user.Put("telephoneNumber", "1234")
$user.Put("thumbnailPhoto", $binaryfile)
$user.SetInfo()
```

But I also have to set the manager and tried

```
$user.Put("manager", "MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME")
```

or

```
$user.Put("manager", "MYUSERNAME")
```

That gives the following error:

> Exception calling "setinfo" with "0" argument(s): "An invalid dn syntax has been specified."

What's the correct syntax to update the manager using ADSI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggests: the `manager` attribute expects a distinguished name (dn), not a user logon name, so you need to get the manager's dn first and then put that value into the `manager` attribute.

```
$manager = 'MYUSERNAME'

#...

$searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(([adsi]''))
$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=${manager}))"
$dn = $searcher.FindOne().Properties['distinguishedName'][0]

#...

$user.Put('manager', $dn)
$user.SetInfo()
```

Comment: That should be `$dn = $searcher.FindOne().Properties["distinguishedName"]`. The `Path` will contain `LDAP://`, which the `manager` attribute won't like. You also could add `$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")` before the search, so that it only retrieves that one attribute you want to use and not every attribute.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thanks for the heads up. I had just cobbled this one together without testing.

Comment: Thanks but whet I use the dn I get another error:
```Exception calling "put" with "2" argument(s): "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))"```

Comment: @jlai79 Apparently `Properties['distinguishedName']` returns a collection, so you need to pick the first element from that collection (`[0]`). See updated answer.